# Building multi-line database queries in python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

Ran into a problem and something that seemed simple at first.

I want to do this (query has been dumbed down for brevity here, it's actually much longer and more complex):

```
    query  = ("""INSERT INTO %s " % cfg['mysql.table']
              "('hostname', 'timestamp', 'metric', 'average', 'peakhigh', 'peaklow', 'gsamp', 'zsamp', 'nsamp')"""
              "VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s )"
             )
```

So how do I incorpoarate STR_TO_DATE into this query for the timestamp field?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try building your query inside triple quotes.

Comment: How do you do this component of the string using the triple quote approach though - "INSERT INTO %s " % cfg['mysql.table']?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put your string inside triple quotes:

```
query  = ("""INSERT INTO %s " % cfg['mysql.table']
              "('hostname', 'timestamp', 'metric', 'average', 'peakhigh', 'peaklow', 'gsamp', 'zsamp', 'nsamp')"
              "VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s )"""
             )
```

Comment: Ok let me try that again, I must have fat-fingered something when I tried this approach before posting.

Comment: Any idea how I incoproate STR_TO_DATE for the timestamp field?

Comment: Try changing the second `%s` with `STR_TO_DATE(%s, '%d/%m/%Y')` if that matches the dd/mm/YYYY format you require.